# Should I use context for this utility class that implements a socket server?

Tags: android, android-context

A little confused about the need for a context when setting up this class shown below.  Do I need context when making an instance of this class to use it in my Activity?

I can set up the constructor for the class one way like this:

```
 public Server(Context myContext)
```

or without context as a parameter, not using context:

```
 public Server()
```

now for more of the code from the Server class:

```
public class Server {

private TextView serverStatus;
public TextView receivedCommand;
public String line = null;

// default ip
 // public static String SERVERIP = "192.168.1.001";
public static String SERVERIP = "localhost";

// designate a port
public static final int SERVERPORT = 8080;

private Handler handler = new Handler();

private ServerSocket serverSocket;


public Server(){
     SERVERIP = getLocalIpAddress();

     Thread fst = new Thread(new ServerThread());
     fst.start();
}


public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

// ... the rest of the code
```

Comment: It depends on whether you need context in that class, do you use it in the Server class? If not, the default constructor will do.

Comment: If it is touching `TextViews` it is not really a server...

Comment: yes,  i forgot to remove the text view references, originally it was extending Activity and i changed it to a service class with only the socket server inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your class extends `android.app.Service` then you already have access to `getApplicationContext()` but having said that the `Context` isn't essential however we commonly use it to access application preferences and directories from inside our Services.